# How do I find the content of an h1 through javascript?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want z to equal "hello", but instead this returns `<h1>Hello</h1>`. How do I fix this?

```
<h1> Hello </h1>

var z = document.getElementById("y");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHTML` (and give your H1 an ID):

```js
var z = document.getElementById("y").innerHTML;
console.log(z)
```

```html
<h1 id="y"> Hello </h1>
```

If you can't give your H1 an ID for some reason you can use [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead:

```js
var z = document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML;
console.log(z)
```

```html
<h1> Hello </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the `id="y"` in `h1` tag .And get the innertext using [`innerHTML`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiBm_jn-bDUAhWMuI8KHfSmDRkQFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FElement%2FinnerHTML&usg=AFQjCNF4R8v2uvjMHLtHGQ5Qj42jZkzM_A&sig2=aKWezi1Y_nKC_KablJfsow) or [`textContent`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwizkMnq-bDUAhXIro8KHSWsDIsQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fprop_node_textcontent.asp&usg=AFQjCNFNFRoQja7SKgrCaSc42uqHbrLjkQ&sig2=jeV_DzKQXF-qo9ztb-uZCg)

```js
var z = document.getElementById("y").innerHTML

console.log(z)
```

```html
<h1 id="y"> Hello </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to get an element content is to use [**textContent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```
var z = document.getElementById("y").textContent;
```

**Demo:**

```js
var z = document.getElementById("y").textContent;

console.log(z);
```

```html
<h1 id="y"> Hello </h1>
```

**Note:**

You need to add `id="y"` to your element, so you can refer it with `document.getElementById()`.